# How to replace string with User Control in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I have such HTML content in database:
`<div class='content'>This is the test text <cms:control name='test' /></div>`

I need to render this content on page, but replace `<cms:control name='test' />` with related user control.

I can not parse control to string, because it might be a complex with ajax controls, validators and so on.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you not use a PlaceHolder and build the user control then assign it that way..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE How can I use Placeholder if my HTML is just a string from database? Ok. I can load it to Placeholder, but how can I replace <cms:control /> element with UserControl in it?

Comment: I am not sure that is possible? You could parse the text and create the control dynamically in code-behind.

Comment: I would retrieve the control in ASP.NET via a sqldatareader and then throw it in a script manager jquery snippet and fire that when i wanted it to render... an abstract answer to an abstract question.

Comment: Both you and I are essentially looking for an equivalent to [WordPress Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode).  [This guy](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/how-to-programmatically-add-user-control-to/368613) was looking for it back in 2005...

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it this way I would suggest using the HTML agility pack to parse and rendering your usercontrols in your pagebehind.

Something like so...

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlFromDB);
var query = doc.DocumentNode.Decendants("cm:control");
foreach(var node in query)
{
   string userControlHTML = GetHTML(new MyUserControl());
   var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(userControlHTML);
   node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, node);
}
//render doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml in literal control on your page
...

static public string GetHTML(Control myControl)
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    myControl.RenderControl(myWriter);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

If your controls are too complex to do it this way you should probably reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your user controls :

```
<div id="loadedControls" runat="server">
</div>
```

In Page Load :

```
loadedControls.LoadControl("UserControllAddress");
```

Comment: You want to load usercontrol dynamically and you have some c# codes in user controls then you should load control not replace it!